# PHP + Appscript (Google Sheets) Login Problem

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having a problem with a login web app aplication, i put the user and password data into the required spaces, but i get nothing but a stringfied error message saying
{"status":"error","message":"Senha requerida"}(The message says "Password Required)
Can anybody help me? I have no idea why this is wrong.

I'll show some of the codes that may have something wrong with them

1- login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Page de Login (teste)</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="formContainer">
        <form method="post" action="login_action.php">
        <h2 class="title">Login</h2>
        <div class="tip">
            log in utilizing email and password
        </div>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email">
        <label for="senha">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="senha">
        <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
        </form>
        <div class="link">
            still don't have an account?<br> <a href="signup.php">Create account</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

2- login_action.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwfzUBRZt0h3OOSF5VSUsciOQLInZ7lOE5WPFOU4UyFtNTzKn958uOq1vjB_XyIP_eAIg/exec";

$postData = [
    "action" => "login",
    "email" => $_POST['email'],
    "password" => $_POST['senha']
];

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
]);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;
```

3-index.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("location: dashboard.php");
} else {
    header("location: login.php");
}
?>
```

4-dashboard.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dashboardContainer">
        <div class="avatar">
            <img src="avatar.png" alt="avatar do usuário">
        </div>
        <div class="welcomeMessage">
            hello <b>MEUNOME</b>, welcome to my website
        </div>
        <div class="notes">
            You can modify this page by editing 'dashboard.php'
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

5- ProjetoLogin.gs

```
//get data
function getDataByEmail(email){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("loginTeste");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var result = null;
  for(var i=1; i<data.length; i++){
    if(data[i][0] == email){
      result = data[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

//login function
function login(email, senha){
  var data = getDataByEmail(email);
  var error = null;

  if(data == null){
    error = "email não registrado";
  }else if(data[1] != senha){
    error = "Senha inválida";
  }

  if(error == null){
    return {
      status: "successo",
      data: {
        email: data[0],
        senha: data[1],
        nome: data[2]
      }
    }
  }else{
    return {
      status: "error",
      message: error
    }
  }
}

//signup function
function signup(email, senha, nome){
  var check = getDataByEmail(email);
  if(check != null){
    return {
      status: "error",
      message: "email já existe"
    }
  }else{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("loginTeste");
    var data = [[email,senha,nome]];
    var row = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    var cel = 1;
    var rowLength = data.length;
    var celLength = data[0].length;
    sheet.getRange(row, cel, rowLength, celLength).setValues(data);
    return {
      status: "successo",
      message: "Inscrição realizada!"
    }
  }
}

// handle POST request
function doPost(e){
  var error = null;
  if(typeof e.parameter.action == 'undefined'){
    error = "parâmetro action requerido";
  }else if(e.parameter.action == "login"){ //LOGIN PROCCESS
    if(typeof e.parameter.email == 'undefined'){
      error = "email requerido";
    }else if(typeof e.parameter.senha == 'undefined'){
      error = "senha requerida";
    }else if(e.parameter.email.trim() == ""){
      error = "email não pode estar vazio";
    }else if(e.parameter.senha.trim() == ""){
      error = "senha não pode estar vazia";
    }else{
      var result = login(e.parameter.email.trim(), e.parameter.senha.trim());
    }
  }else if(e.parameter.action == "signup"){ //SIGNUP PROCCESS
    if(typeof e.parameter.email == 'undefined'){
      error = "email requerido";
    }else if(typeof e.parameter.senha == 'undefined'){
      error = "senha requerida";
    }else if(typeof e.parameter.nome == 'undefined'){
      error = "nome requerido";
    }else if(e.parameter.email.trim() == ""){
      error = "email não pode estar vazio";
    }else if(e.parameter.senha.trim() == ""){
      error = "senha não pode estar vazia";
    }else if(e.parameter.nome.trim() == ""){
      error = "nome não pode estar vazio";
    }else{
      var result = signup(e.parameter.email.trim(), e.parameter.senha.trim(), e.parameter.nome.trim());
    }
  }else{
    error = "unknown action";
  }

  if(error != null){
    var result = {
      status: 'error',
      message: error
    }
  }

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result));
}

//handle GET request
function doGet(e){
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
    status: "error",
    message: "Method GET não permitido"
  }))
}

function test(){
  var data = signup("user5@example.com", "shinmas", "shinmatsu");
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

at last, i'll give the pic of the sheet i've stored info on
[User Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbxQ3.png)

I've tried talking to the person who made the code (No communications, looked for people who had the same problem at stackerflow but didn't find a good answer and i tried looking for group communities who code in google appscript to see if they could help me. Unfortunately, no luck.

Comment: Sounds like your password is not making it to the authentication script.  Can you show me where you enter it.

Comment: Try adding this to the signup function):

    `function signup(email, senha, nome){
      Logger.log('Password: %s',senha);//see if you are getting it here
      var check = getDataByEmail(email);`
      if(check != null){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your showing scripts, in your PHP, `$postData` is `[ "action" => "login", "email" => $_POST['email'], "password" => $_POST['senha'] ];`. The keys are `action`, `email`, and `password`. But, in `doPost`, `e.parameter.action`, `e.parameter.email`, `e.parameter.senha`, and `e.parameter.nome` are used. In this case, `senha` and `nome` are not given from PHP. You error message is `but a stringfied error message saying {"status":"error","message":"Senha requerida"}(The message says "Password Required)`. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification? In this modification, `login_action.php` is modified.

#### From:

```
"password" => $_POST['senha']
```

#### To:

```
"senha" => $_POST['senha']
```

#### Note:

- Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation, when the values of `action`, `email`, and `password` are valid values, I guess that `{"status":"successo","data":{,,,}}` might be returned.
- `nome` is not included in the request of PHP. I cannot understand your actual situation. So, in this answer, I proposed a modification point for removing your current issue of `but a stringfied error message saying {"status":"error","message":"Senha requerida"}(The message says "Password Required)`.